# perform action after time react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am changing my state based on an user input. Like this :

```
    <form>
        <input type='text' onChange={handleSearchChange} placeholder='Zoeken'></input>
    </form>
```

and the handler :

```
const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    setSearchKey(e.target.value.toLowerCase().trim());
}
```

setSearchKey sets the state. I would like to call the setSearchKey function when the user stops typing for atleast 0.5 second. Right now the function gets called as soon as the user types, but i want the user to type and 0.5 seconds after the user typed call the set function. Is this possible with setTimeOut , not sure how to implement this in my case.

Comment: Did you try wrapping `setSearchKey` inside `setTimeout` ?I am hoping it should work

Comment: I don't use react but presumably you could use this method: https://jsfiddle.net/wpy3ndc0/ . The timeout will be reset each time the input changes. It might be better to use `onInput` to clear the timeout so that the function doesn't run whilst still typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a timeOut ref:

```
const timeOut = useRef(null);
```

Then modify your handleSearchChange:

```
const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(timeOut.current);
    timeOut.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setSearchKey(e.target.value.toLowerCase().trim());
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: where does the ref go? is it in the handler?

Comment: put the ref at the beginning of your component